# Make clickable just one of the two response on Google form

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

i'm trying to make a google form with a multiple choice question,with 2 possible answer. But I want that people can click just the second one if they already click the first one before and the first one only if they had already click the second one.

Example:

Mark go to the office and select "Office IN"(Option 1) and he can't select Option 2 because he's already out of the office.

Mark leave the office and select "Office OUT"(Option 2) and he can't select Option 1 because he's already inside the office.

And restart.

Thanks!

Comment: "But I want that people can click just the second one if they already click the first one before and the first one only if they had already click the second one." Interesting scenario - they can't click the second question unless they have already clicked the first question, however they can't click the first question unless they have already clicked the second question?? Perhaps it would be better to expand on your question using some actual information; as it stands, your question is quite confusing.

Comment: Sorry, of course there is a beginning of this circle. I will try to expand my question, thanks, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Is this the actual scenario you are trying to manage, or just an example?

Comment: actual scenario, not compleate, but yes

Comment: You are trying to make Google Forms jump through hoops for which it was not designed. To deliver your outcome, each user would have to sign in to use the form, and you would need a unique form for each user since you must programatically update each specific the form to alter the multiple choice options. You would be better off looking at a webapp where you have an HTML form and you can control the interaction between the form and Google Sheets dynamically and in real time. You could use a single form (user selects their name from a dropdown) and then populate questions based on the user ID.